# Highlighting rows with DataTables (or other table/grid plug-ins)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

There's an example in DataTables for highlighting rows on hover:
http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/highlight.html

However, I'm looking for something a bit different. I'd like the highlight to be trigged when users click on words outside the table. For example, in the above link, I'd like row #2 to be highlighted when a user click on "visibility" in the text above the table (so it's kind of a hyperlink).

I'm assuming I can find an highlighting plug-in that maybe can do what I need. But before 
I got there, is there any easy way to do this with DateTables or other table/grid plug-ins?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of [highlight on click](http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html).

It also has an example of deleting a row on click from a link outside the table.

EDIT: This example won't do exacly what you want, but it get's you most of the way there.  I have retrofitted [the example in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q332z/) to do what you want.  Here is the "click link to highlight row" part of it:

```
$("#rowHighlightLink").click(function(event) {
    $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
        $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
    });
    $('#example tbody tr').eq(1).addClass('row_selected');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you point me to the "deleting a row on click from a link outside the table" example? I see a delete example but it seems to work only when clicking on another row *inside* the table.

Comment: @user247866 sorry it wasn't an exact example.  Check out my latest edit for a proof of concept of what you want.